# Multi-instance of FCK in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, fckeditor

I got a problem when I put 2 instances of FckEditor to a page in dotnetnuke. 
sometimes, I got empty text when I call the text property.

Anyone helps?

Comment: Which version of DotNetNuke? What version of the FCKeditor provider are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The empty `Text` property is usually caused by having the editor in an update panel (either explicitly or by turning on partial rendering for that control definition).

Comment: No, I didn't put it in an update panel and the partial rendering was also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

> For those using the FCKEditor on their
>   dotnetnuke sites, I recommend updating
>   to the latest version, it fixes a
>   number of problems including multiple
>   instances on the same page. (something
>   you will need for the latest news
>   articles).
>   [Source](http://www.ventrian.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/243/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/286/FCKEditor-Update.aspx)
>   [Download](http://dnnfckeditor.codeplex.com/) the latest version of the FCKeditor provider.